# Unable to open JenkinsCI connector in MS Teams

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, microsoft-teams

In our project, we were trying to setup 'JenkinsCI Connector' in MS Teams but in vain. Though, we are able to add it in one of channel in Teams but unfortunately NOT able to open it. Any suggestion??

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Are you trying this with JenKins inbuilt app? Please refer below image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4dVw.png
Is this same? If not, could you please share the repro steps to try at our end?

Comment: Yes, exactly same. We are able to add it into out MS Teams channel successfully. But, unable to open and configure it. After clicking on 'Open' button - it's again redirecting us to search page.

Comment: We are able to repro your issue and raised the bug for the same. We will let you know once we get any updates on it.